Secure Shell Remote Connection goes to wrong VM
I execute script on large number of linux VMs using parallel connection (At a time maximum parallel connection 500 with Random sleep 300 secs).
The issue is some of them goes to wrong VM and execute script.
When i checked manual ssh to VM in other iterm session (at the same time when parallel connection exec is in-progress), it is actually going to wrong VM (always random on VM).
e.g
ubuntu@admin:~$ ssh 10.10.97.2 "hostname -i"
10.10.13.47
ubuntu@admin:~$ ssh 10.10.97.2 "hostname -i"
10.10.13.4
ubuntu@admin:~$ ssh 10.10.97.2 "hostname -i"
10.10.12.90

I have added below entry in my ssh config but no luck
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/socket_pool/%C
ControlPersist yes

It always change connect to wrong IP (at the same time when parallel connection exec is in-progress in other session).
Anyone suggest me what is wrong in my ubuntu VM ?

What's the output of ip a on the machine?

When those target machines have multiple interfaces or multiple names (resolv'able names, like DNS or NBNS), this is the expected output. Not because the script is connecting to the wrong machines, but because of the expected output. Be very careful using hostname -i.
The man page for linux hostname command is very specific about the difference:
-i, --ip-address
     Display  the  network address(es) of the host name. Note that this works only if the
     host name can be resolved.
     Avoid using this option; use hostname --all-ip-addresses instead.
-I, --all-ip-addresses
     Display all network addresses of the host. This option enumerates all configured addresses on all network interfaces.
     The  loopback interface and IPv6 link-local addresses are omitted. Contrary to option -i, this option does not depend
     on name resolution. Do not make any assumptions about the order of the output.

